# Can dump file version be specified with svnrdump?

Tags: svn, svndump, svndumpfilter

I need to create a dump file of a network repository. I'd like to do this using the network friendly svn tool, [svnrdump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) as opposed to the regular svndump. However, I also need to use the [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) tool as there is much in this repo which I do not require (many projects share this repo, and I only wish to dump one project).

I encountered the following error when trying to use svndumpfilter - `E140001: Unsupported dumpfile version: 3`. According to [this](http://kgirlssworld.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/svn-repository-migration.html) article, this is due to svnradmin using a newer version of the svn dump file format than svndumpfilter can handle.

My question is, can the required dump file format version be specified when using svnrdump so that I can use svndumpfilter?

Answer (score 4):

You could recreate a repository out of your **svnrdump**-created dump, dump it again with **svnadmin dump** command and use **svndumpfilter* on this new dumpfile

Could take a while if your repo is quite large..

Comment: I've upvoted as I'm sure this will work, but I have a problem with a path in my repo which is causing a `svnadmin: E720232: Can't write to stream: The pipe is being closed.` error. This is after about 6 hours of it running happily... Maybe I'll experiment with a smaller test network-hosted repository sometime

Comment: You can disect your dump into smaller parts, maybe then it is easier to test and find the problem..